# How to open complete tree with children by default on landing?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-tree-component

I have implemented `ngx-bootstrap-treeview`

Currently with `[isOpened]="true"` is opening First Level tree only but I have secondly level tree as well which is not opening until I click on it. I tried to find out solution in documentation + PRs but i did not find anything.

```
<ngx-bootstrap-treeview [isOpened]="true" 
[openedFolderIcon]="faTemplate" 
[closedFolderIcon]="faTemplate"
[isAnimationDisabled]="true"
[selectedLeafIcon]="faTemplate"
[unselectedLeafIcon]="faTemplate"
[tree]="certPathTree" ></ngx-bootstrap-treeview>
```

I have tree like below :

```
>Root
   >> Level 1.1
   >> Level 1.2
         >>> Level 2.1
         >>> Level 2.2
         >>> Level 2.3
```

But It is Showing like below:

```
>Root
   >> Level 1.1
   >> Level 1.2
```

If I want to see

```
>>> Level 2.1
>>> Level 2.2
>>> Level 2.3
```

Then I have to click on `> Level 1.2`

Can anyone please help me on same? Please do let me know if anyone need further information.
[enter link description here](https://github.com/Zokelion/ngx-bootstrap-treeview)
Library link : https://github.com/Zokelion/ngx-bootstrap-treeview

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to your `NgxBootstrapTreeviewComponent` and call `unfoldAll()`:

```
@ViewChild('tree') tree: NgxBootstrapTreeviewComponent;
ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.tree.unfoldAll();
}
```